# Cant escape a string with addcslashes()

Tags: php, string

I am trying ot learn how to escape simple characters. I print the ASCII of the character >. 
But when I print it after using the function addcslashes..nothing is escaped. Why is that?

```
     $da=ord('>'); 
     echo $da."<br/>";
     $not_escaped="><?";
      $escaped = addcslashes($not_escaped, "\61...\64");
      echo  $escaped;
```

I followed their documentations..but my example above doesnt work.
Thye also use 2 seperators !@ between the range of ASCII number range..what does it mean?

```
$escaped = addcslashes($not_escaped, "\0..\37!@\177..\377");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ASCII codes in the `$charlist` are octal, not decimal. So to escape ">" (decimal: 62, octal: 76), use this code:

```
$escaped = addcslashes($not_escaped, "\76");
```

For a range, use two dots and not three ('a..z', not 'a...z').

Comment: Their documentation dont say so..if i want two ranges..do I include these symbols?

Comment: > characters with ASCII codes lower than 32 and higher than 126 converted to *octal representation*.

Comment: Multiple ranges: `$escaped = addcslashes($not_escaped, "a..c!@k..m"); // escape a-c and k-m`

Comment: what about characters  between 32 and 126.. is tehir representation is decimal

Comment: No, all the ASCII codes should be octal. ;) > they are converted in C-like style, [...] to octal representation.

Comment: lol..why the hell did they say that: characters with ASCII codes lower than 32 and higher than 126 converted to octal representation. ... if all of them should be ocatal?